# Table inside a table appearance problem

Tags: tables, formatting

I am wondering what I am doing wrong formatting the table. I want to have a table in every cell of the other table, each should be subscripted with a text. Please copy the following code to your LaTeX editor, if you would like to answer the questions.

I have an outside table := OT and three inside tables := IT.

You see, I have a `\toprule`. If I try to enter the `\bottomrule` before the end od the OT, the document no more compiles (try to uncomment it in the code). If I enter a word inside a cell of the OT before or after the IT and separate the word with a `\\` like `word \\` or `\\ word`, I get strong table appereance problems, which I cannot understand (try to uncomment all the "words" in the document).

Could you please try these two points out and tell me where my mistake in formatting is?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\centering
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.4cm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
\toprule %\\ word
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} 
        \cline{1-3} f&f&f\\ \cline{1-3} t&t&t\\ \cline{1-3} \cellcolor[gray]{0}t&t&t \\ \cline{1-3}
        \end{tabular}  
& %\\ word
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} 
        \cline{1-3} t&t&t\\ \cline{1-3} \cellcolor[gray]{0}t&t&t\\ \cline{1-3} t&t&t \\ \cline{1-3}
        \end{tabular}  
& %\\ word
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} 
        \cline{1-3} t&t&t\\ \cline{1-3} \cellcolor[gray]{0}t&t&t\\ \cline{1-3}t &t&t \\ \cline{1-3}
        \end{tabular}  
%\bottomrule
\end{tabular} \\
\end{document}
```

[image: decription]

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't it a series of subtables, each with its subcaption  you want?

Comment: I'm afraid your write-up isn't all that clear. It sounds like there are several, unconnected issues. To start with, the sentence "If I try to enter the `\bottomrule` before the end od the OT, the error comes" is quite confusing: *Which* error? As there is no `\bottomrule` instruction in your code, it's not clear what may be going (or what should go on). Separately, since there are currently no "words" in any of the cells, it's well-nigh impossible to diagnose what it is you need to fix. Please edit your posting to clarify what it is you're trying to get done.

Comment: @Mico I've corrected the code and added instructions.

Comment: @Bernard, I've added the illustration above to show how it should look like and what happens if I enter some text.

Comment: @Bernard, and yes, sure, I want to be able to enter some text under each smaller table. Just wondering why everything jumps so crazy, if I enter this text.

Comment: That is because you didn't see the three ‘word’s have to be on their own row: each time you wrote `\\word`, you created a new row of the `outer` table.

Comment: @Bernard the idea was: "I am in the cell. I make another table and want to break the line after it and write some text." I did not even think that the editor will interprete `\\\` as a row break, not a line break. I hope that I get it. Thank you!

Comment: It's not the editor which interprets, it's TeX itself. See my second code: inside an inner tabular, \\  is interpreted as a so-to-say local row change. If you're in the outer table, it is a row change in the outer table. TeX does not try to guess your wishes :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I rewrote this answer significantly after the OP provided further, crucial information about his/her formatting needs.)

The following may be what you're looking for. Some of the changes I've applied to your code are: (a) encase the "inner" `tabular` environments in `subtable` environments; (b) use `\caption*` directives to typeset the captions; (c) no vertical bars between the inner `tabular` environments`; (d) make sure the lines drawn by`\toprule`and`\bottomrule`are no wider than the material they encase; (e) use a lighter coloring for the cells; and (f) use`\hline`rather than`\cline{1-3}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,ragged2e,subcaption}
\captionsetup[subtable]{justification=Centering} % or: ...=RaggedRight
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newlength\mylength % define length variable
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{table}
\centering
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.4cm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
% Calculate overall width of the 3x3 subtables
\settowidth\mylength{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}t&t&t\end{tabular}}

\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}} % outer tabular
\toprule 
\begin{subtable}[t]{\mylength}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} % first inner tabular
        \hline f&f&f\\ 
        \hline t&t&t\\ 
        \hline \cellcolor[gray]{0.75}t&t&t \\ 
        \hline 
        \end{tabular}
        \caption*{first table, with a two-line caption}
\end{subtable}        
& 
\begin{subtable}[t]{\mylength}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} % second inner tabular
        \hline t&t&t\\ 
        \hline \cellcolor[gray]{0.75}t&t&t\\ 
        \hline t&t&t \\ 
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption*{second table, with an even longer caption}
\end{subtable}
& 
\begin{subtable}[t]{\mylength}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} % third inner tabular
        \hline t&t&t\\ 
        \hline \cellcolor[gray]{0.75}t&t&t\\ 
        \hline t&t&t \\ 
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption*{third table, with a tremendously long, fancy, and elaborate caption}
\end{subtable} \\ % <--- the "\\" directive is important
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, @Mico and thank you. That looks good and could be a solution. But, if you enter `\\ some more text` after every `\end{tabular}` of the smaller tables, the formatting "jumps" again. I mean, it is a good solution, but it is good for some words. If I want to write a sentence into the `multicolumn` part, the formatting will be bad. I want to be able to write more text under the tables. Thank you again.

Comment: @Kirill - I am probably one of the world's worst psychics. (By the way, the psychic powers of most participants on this site are every bit as bad as mine...) If your write-up doesn't mention that "word" is, in fact, not supposed to be "word" at all but, rather, a potentially quite long string of words, I am simply not in a position to guess correctly what it is that you really *meant* to say. Please edit your query to state exactly what you really want to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited the post twice, added comments to the code. If I have expressed myself not well-defined, sorry, I always try to express myself in a better manner, but I do not have much experience expressing myself in English. The first question was as it is - 1) why uncommenting `bottomrule` leads to an error and 2) why breaking the line after or before the smaller tables affects the layout as shown in the picture above...

Comment: actually, it is. The first alternative gives me an ability to break lines, although manually. If I could, I would choose both answers as best, because they both solve the problem that even was not formulated in the way one can understand it, as you say. I have tested your answer, and it works perfectly. Although, I need to learn something to understand how it works. You define the variable that calculates the length of the table in the line 8 adn 17. How it works? What package defines subtables? I haven't know that the commands exists. Is `\captionsetup` a TeX or a package command?Thnks

Comment: @Kirill - The `subcaption` provides the environment called `subtable` and, indirectly, the macros  `\captionsetup` and `\caption*`. The `\newlength` and `\settowidth` macros are part of the LaTeX "kernel" -- no extra packages needed.

Comment: thank you! The p.s.-question: how can I change the font-size of the captions in your code?

Comment: @Kirill - State the desired font size as an option passed to `\captionsetup`. E.g., `\captionsetup{font=small, ...}` or `\captionsetup{font=footnotesize, ...}`

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to obtain you want, if I've well understood. I replaced loading `colortbl` with `xcolor`and option `table` (which loads colortbl, and adds some commands for colouring tables).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\centering
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.4cm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
\toprule
\addlinespace[2ex]
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
         \hline f&f&f\\ \hline t&t&t\\  \hline \cellcolor[gray]{0}t&t&t \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
 & \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline t&t&t\\ \hline \cellcolor[gray]{0}t&t&t\\ \hline  t&t&t \\ \hline%
    \end{tabular}
&
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline  t&t&t\\ \hline  \cellcolor[gray]{0}t&t&t\\ \hline  t &t&t \\ \hline
        \end{tabular} \\ %
        word & word & word \\
        \bottomrule
\end{tabular} \\
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
\toprule
\addlinespace[2ex]
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline  f&f&f\\ \hline  t&t&t\\ \hline  \cellcolor[gray]{0}t&t&t \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{word}
        \end{tabular}
 & \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline  t&t&t\\ \hline  \cellcolor[gray]{0}t&t&t\\ \hline  t&t&t \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{word}
        \end{tabular}
&
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline  t&t&t\\ \hline  \cellcolor[gray]{0}t&t&t\\ \hline t &t&t \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{word}
        \end{tabular} \\
        \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the second one does not allow me to break lines, if I have more text than just two words; but the second one works perfectly! Could you please explain, why my tables were displayed not correctly? I mentioned that you have added `addlinespace` and exchanged `cline`s with `hlines`, but it is not the reason, or? Existed the problem because of the package?

Comment: No, it' s not the reason. I replaced `\cline` because it was unnecessary. W.r.t. the inner tables, it is a full `\hline`, and it's simpler to type. `\addlinespace`at the top is there for aesthetic reasons (the vertical spacing was too tight for me). I gave an explantion in a comment to your post. Isn't it clear enough? Last point: for the second solution (which is simpler from a semantic point of view), you still can break lines  with the `makecell` package, but you'll have to do it by hand.

Comment: Yes, I have seen it there after I wrote this question here :) Kindly thank you.